# Setting PHP variables from AJAX/Json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

At the moment I have this code:

index.php

```
      var refreshId = setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
  url: ("http://www.example.co.uk/erc/user_data.php?imei="+inCallingNum),
  dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
  success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
    $('#right-side').html(data.rightside);
        $('#caller').html(data.caller);
        $('.location').html(data.location);
        $('.battery-level').html(data.battery);
        //parse the json data
  }
});
    });
```

user_data.php

```
$profile = array();
$profile['rightside'] = $rightside;
$profile['caller'] = $caller;
$profile['nextofkin'] = $nextofkin;
$profile['location'] = $location;
$profile['battery'] = $battery;

echo json_encode($profile);
```

This works fine to add the information into the div tags, but what I need to do now is take a PHP variable from the user_data.php file and use it in the index.php file. Is it possible to send/capture PHP variables in that way?

E.g. in user_data.php I have a variable $test and I want to use this $test variable in index.php

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this, and the easiest (and most transparent way of doing so) is by setting a session cookie.  This is a small file that sits on the client's computer, and is readable by all sites on your sub-domain (x.mydomain.com.), basically all files in that same folder as the file that set it.  You can do this easily in PHP by doing the following things:

1. On EVERY page you want to set, get, or otherwise check for the variables... use this code

   ```
   session_start();  // Put this at the TOP of your page, below <? or just before you check the variables.
   ```
2. On the page you want to SET the variables... use this code

   ```
   $_SESSION['variable'] = "data";
   session_write_close();  // Use this after you are done setting the session data, to save it before the page execution is finished.  This is a good habit to get in to, it's kind of like when you fclose a file instead of waiting for the script to do it.
   ```
3. On the page you want to GET the variables.. use this code

   ```
   $test = $_SESSION['variable'];
   ```

You can basically use the $_SESSION array to store variables you want to be seen as "global" on your site.  Forums use this to store the User ID and session hash, for later authentication on passwords.  Other sites use session cookies to limit user activity within a given timeframe.

--

There is also another way you can do this, have a link from your page that generates the value of $test send a GET request to index.php (for example, if the user clicks a link format the link like:

```
index.php?test=value
```

Then on index.php simply do:

```
$test = $_GET{'test'];
```

This method is good for users who may not have cookie support, or may have cookies disabled; but is very obvious, and users can easily change the value of the cookie (which can have unseen results.)

Comment: hi cbroughton, thanks for your help. I'll give this a try and let you know how i get on :)

Comment: it works well, but i've now got another question so I'll make a new post. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for cannot really be done since index.php is executed before user_data.php. However, since you are sending the result from user_data.php to index.php maybe you can look at consuming the variable with JavaScript. Why not tell us more about what you would like to accomplish so we can suggest how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

either set `$test` into `$_SESSION['test']` and get it on *index.php*

alternative:

did u try with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer to your question in the question!

Even though you are creating and array to encode as JSON you are in fact just passing values from php to javascript.

You could equally do

```
$profile['test'] = $test;
```

and then in your javascript use

```
data.test
```

to get your value.

The question is when are you wanting to get the varaible value? Is it before the page is served or during your ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your JavaScript code dynamically, with PHP:

```
alert("server name: <?php
  echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>");
```

Use it with caution, just in rare cases.